# What does the array.includes() method giving false for checking existence of an array/object within another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is my code :

```
let x = new Array();
x.push(2);
x.push({'Drake': 12, age: 5})
x.push([1, 7, 4, 12, 19]);

console.log(typeof x);
console.log(x);

console.log(x.includes({'Drake': 12, age: 5}));
console.log(x.includes(2));
console.log(x.includes( [1, 7, 4, 12, 19] ));
```

The output of the middle console statement is true, but they other two are false. How do I correctly check if another object or an array is included in another array in Javascript ? Any help is appreciated, need to hone my objects skills in Javascript.

Comment: In javascript, `[1,2,3]` and another `[1,2,3]` are two different objects. Sad, but true.

Comment: Not really sad, but decidedly true. If `a === b` then `a` and `b` are interchangeable in JavaScript. Two different arrays aren’t interchangeable (e.g. if you push to one it won’t affect the other).